# Using segues and storyboards, if you pop a UIViewController it doesn't get destroyed

Tags: ios6, uistoryboard, xcode4.5, uistoryboardsegue

I have been getting memory warnings in my app which is what brought this to my attention. I have a navigation controller and its root view controller. From this root view controller I push another view controller onto the navigation stack via calling:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]
```

The segue is from the root view controller to the new view controller and of mode PUSH.

I then remove this view controller and pop back to the root view controller by calling

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The problem is that if I push and pop the view controller around 20 times I start to get memory warnings.

didRecieveMemoryWarning is called approx 20 times on the view controller in a single frame signifying that that every popped view controller is still hanging about.

The app then eventually crashes.

I have no stored references to the pushed view controller anywhere.

I'm using ios6 so I know the viewDidUnload() will not get called.

I am removing all cached images when I get the memory warnings but ideally destroying the old popped view controllers is the way forward but I do not know how to do this using storyboards.

If I was manually calling pushViewController from code I could maintain a single object reference to re-use each time so I do not keep creating new view controllers to push but that's going back a step away from storyboards.

Any help in this matter is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Stewart.

Comment: Have you overridden dealloc in your popped view controller to see if it ever gets called? If not then some other object must be holding a reference to it.